# Acumatica - Filtering PO Inventory Selector By Current Vendor

Tags: filter, attributes, acumatica

I have a customer that wants the Inventory Selector in POLine to only contain inventory items that belong to the selected vendor in POOrder.  Is there a way to add a join to [POLineInventoryItem(Filterable=true)]? Or some other way I should go about this?

If I replace with new pxselector the inventory item does not pass to po line.  Also, I will lose the CrossAttribute search.  This is the Acumatica code:

```
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[POLineInventoryItem(Filterable = true)]
[PXForeignReference(typeof(FK.InventoryItem))]
```

This is the selector I need:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<InventoryItem.inventoryID,
InnerJoin<POVendorInventory, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID,    
Equal<POVendorInventory.inventoryID>,
And<POVendorInventory.vendorID, Equal<Current<POOrder.vendorID>>>>>>))]

[PXCustomizeSelectorColumns(
typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.inventoryCD),
typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.descr),
typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.itemClassID),
typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.itemType),
typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.baseUnit),
typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.salesUnit),
typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.purchaseUnit),
typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.basePrice),
typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.itemStatus))]
```

When I replace the selector with the one @Brian suggested, even with a leftjoin, I get back a SQL syntax error happening in this snippet in profiler:

```
FROM [InventoryItem] [InventoryItem]
WHERE ( [InventoryItem].[CompanyID] = 2) AND 
[InventoryItem].[DeletedDatabaseRecord] = 0 AND 
( [InventoryItem].[InventoryID] = )
ORDER BY [InventoryItem].[UsrCaseQty]), 
(SELECT TOP (1) [InventoryItem].[BaseItemVolume]
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated: The previous answer did not apply as the existing selector does not include the needed DAC, so we need to use redefine the selector as well.  If we use the MergeMethod Append, the original attribute will still return all results, so this selector will be ignored.  Since we are using Replace, we need to include all other attributes that we want included.

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Replace)]
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<InventoryItem.inventoryID,
        InnerJoin<POVendorInventory, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID,
        Equal<POVendorInventory.inventoryID>,
        And<POVendorInventory.vendorID, Equal<Current<POOrder.vendorID>>>>>>),
    typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryID),
    typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD),
    typeof(InventoryItem.descr),
    typeof(InventoryItem.itemClassID),
    typeof(InventoryItem.itemType),
    typeof(InventoryItem.baseUnit),
    typeof(InventoryItem.salesUnit),
    typeof(InventoryItem.purchaseUnit),
    typeof(InventoryItem.basePrice),
    typeof(InventoryItem.itemStatus),
    SubstituteKey = typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD)
    )]
protected virtual void POLine_InventoryID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
```

You could do this in a DAC extension, but this example assumes you only want this in a specific screen/graph.  The use of CacheAttached will override the field, but only from the graph where defined.

Note that this example should work for what you asked specifically, but my tests shows that it also will prevent showing the inventory ID of a PO Line if there is no PO Vendor Inventory record tying a pre-existing line to the current vendor.

Comment: I thought about that first...wouldn't POVendorInventory need to be linked to POLineInventoryItem in order to use it in the Where clause or as a restrictor?

Comment: You are correct.  I saw your selector example and misread.  I still stand behind the PXRestrictor, but you need either to redefine the field or the attribute so that you pull that table in.  You can use **[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Replace)]** to substitute your attributes in lieu of the standard ones.  I'll update the answer showing your selector being used to override the standard definition in a graph extension.

Comment: I've been playing around with this off and on since I saw your answer and can't seem to get around a sql error.  When I replace the selector with this code and look at sql profiler I see that there is no value in InventoryID which causes a syntax error.  I thought it might have to do with existing records with PO Line Inventory items not linked to vendor but it happens even if I leftjoin. Any ideas?